# how to get last_inserted_id in ezsql latest version 4?

Tags: database, ezsql

Trying to get last inserted id using this line:
$db->insert_id;

but it doesn't return anything in the latest version of ezsql.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

No one posted an answer, what I did finding the last id inserted into the table, like this

```
$last_inserted = $this->db->get_var("select product_id from oc_product order by product_id desc");
```

maybe there is a direct solution but I searched the documentation and didn't find it, so I used this line of code.

Answer (score 1):

Using a select to get the last id may work but not always. If 2 users or more are inserting at the same time, you may not get the right id. `$db->insert_id` has been replaced by `$db->getInsert_Id()`